# Faking a Scrollbar width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a overflow-x: scroll div, with some content in it. However, the content is supposed to be pretty large, so I would like to ajax load it in dependent upon how far the user has scrolled. But I can't come up with a good way to make the scrollbar appear appear like there is content further away, when the content is yet to be displayed.

My solutions so far have revolved around creating a fake "padding" div on either side with its width set dependent on the scrollbar's position. However, I find that upon the updating of these widths, the scroll bar gets quite jumpy.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/UDnjC/

You just make an inner wrapper and use `min-width` and/or `min-height` to force the scroll-bar on the outer wrapper.

***Demo with horizontal scrolling:*** http://jsfiddle.net/UDnjC/1/

***Alternative solution:*** http://jsfiddle.net/UDnjC/2/

Comment: cool, is there anything wrong cross-browser of just throwing into the wrapper a 1px height, 2000px width div that is absolutely positioned at top:0 and left: 0? (Assuming you make wrapper position: relative)

Comment: @Joda Not with absolute positioning, but with floating. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Do you mean that absolute positioning may have cross-browser issues or floating?

Comment: @Joda When an element is absolutely positioned, it "stops being" a child of the wrapper, it breaks out of that relationship. As a result, the wrapper won't have a scroll bar. On the other hand, if an element is floated, it will generate the scroll bar, as my demo shows.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would do this sort of thing, would be have the actual content div nested inside the div with the scrollbar, with that inner div having some large pre-set width.